# Как правильно записать слово "тату-инфо"?

Tags: слитно-дефис, сложные-слова

Насколько корректно написание слова ***тату-инфо***  и как это **объяснить** **по правилам** (можно ли найти  ссылку):

*Оттянув левый рукав куртки, он быстро заскользил пальцем по нумерованным секторам **тату-инфо** на запястье.*

Для сравнения: ***инфостенд,*** слитное написание. Но формант ***инфо*** здесь в препозиции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шерон, по-моему, здесь одно очевидно: надо писать *тату инфо*. Причина в том, что вторая часть — это слово, которое не склоняется (как и первая часть): http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=65#pp65. (Там это в 122-м параграфе, а именно в 3-м пункте.)

Comment: Там обе части не употребляются в русском языке, а тату в словаре есть.  Сравнить: уроки онлайн.  Оба слова есть в языке.

Comment: Но *инфо* же несклоняемая.

Comment: Так в языке нет этого слова, оно несамостоятельное. Найдите такой пример, как тату инфо.

Comment: Я больше склоняюсь к бездефисному варианту, так как слово *тату* есть, а *инфо* — вид татуировки.

Comment: Тату инфо произносится в два слова, а тату-инфо – слитно. Как вы произносите?

Comment: С ударением на *Инфо*, то есть *тату Инфо*.

Comment: Пауза важна: тату инфо  словосочетание, пауза и два ударения, тату-инфо произносится практически без паузы, основное ударение в конце.

Answer (score 2):

В Нац-корпусе встречается множество неологизмов с префиксом «инфо», произошедшим от слова "информация": инфополе, инфоповод, инфопространство, инфобизнес, инфовзаимодействие, ИнфоВизор, инфографика, инфоголод,  инфодеятельность, инфоДонор, инфокиоск, инфокоммуникационный, инфокарта, инфологема, Инфомат (позволяет пользователям получать: информацию о государственных услугах...), инфомагистраль, Инфонет, инфосфера, инфоструктура, инфосеть, инфосистема и пр...
Среди них есть и забавные: инфоголик, инфозавр.

Слова с «инфо» на конце практически отсутствуют. Думается потому, что такой способ словообразования не подходит для нашего языка и такие примеры как: газета «Спид-инфо», фонд «ФОМ-Инфо», зарубежные геоинформационные системы «Арк-инфо» и «Мар-инфо», учебно-информационный центр НОУ «Кадр-Инфо», - скорее подтверждают, чем опровергают это предположение. Тут дефис "спасает" неуклюжие слова.

Сведение в одно слово сокращений тату(ировка) + инфо(рмация) мне кажется замысловатым и, более того, - противоестественным. Предлагаю не искать правил написания явно неудачного неологизма «тату-инфо», а просто забыть о его существовании.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все интересно, но мне нравится выражение тату-инфо. Это же татуировка в виде компьютера из нашего возможного будущего (фантастика). Если бы   в языке  было самостоятельное существительное ИНФО, то проблем бы не было: тогда это приложение в постпозиции.  Вот я и думаю: может, есть это самостоятельное слово. Или так: другие иноязычные форманты встречаются в постпозиции? Только нужно, чтобы они не были самостоятельными.

Comment: Викисловарь фиксирует существительное в форме «инфа», но про «инфо» - ничего не ведает. Интересно, что в нац-корпусе все наоборот, - примеры использования существительного «инфо» нашлись, а вот «инфа» мне как то не встретилась.

Comment: Мне показалось, что фраза (с примером употребления «тату-инфо») живописует момент подглядывания экзаменуемого в тату-шпаргалку. Если это так, то «скользить» следовало взглядом, но не «пальцем», что бы не выдать себя. Кроме того отметим, что «на запястье» может разместиться весьма ограниченное количество (различимых) символов. Столь ничтожный объем информации куда быстрее и проще ЗАПОМНИТЬ, чем НАКОЛОТЬ.
В этой фразе сюрреализма больше, чем фантастики.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе аж [50 текстов с инфой](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CjgqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCFQoTChEKA3JlcRIKCgjQmNC90YTQsDAB) (и это только в именит. падеже).

Comment: Инфа - сокращ. информация, сленг? В книге это именно мини-компьютер, который персонаж использует для связи со своим виртуальным секретарем. Тот добывает информацию  из разных источников и передает шефу. Интернета у них вроде бы нет. А в офисе секретарь существует как привидение. Очень симпатичный герой.